# pfSense: What package may I install for the `make` command?

Tags: package-management, compiling, freebsd, pfsense

I  have installed pfSense (**FreeBSD** based) in order to test it and learn.

The first thing I want to do is installing some undetected network card (Silicom PXG6BPi) driver, but it needs **compiling** its source with the `make` command, so I issue:

```
[2.2.6-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.localdomain]/root: pkg search make
R-cran-pkgmaker-0.22           Package development utilities
automake-1.15_1                GNU Standards-compliant Makefile generator
automake-wrapper-20131203      Wrapper script for GNU automake
bmake-20151022                 Portable version of NetBSD 'make' utility
ciso-maker-1.02                Tool to compress ISO images to CSO format
cmake-3.4.1                    Cross-platform Makefile generator
cmake-fedora-2.3.4             Set of cmake modules for fedora developers
cmake-gui-3.4.1                Qt-based GUI for CMake
cmake-modules-3.4.1            Modules and Templates for CMake
cmake-modules-webos-1.0.b      CMake modules needed to build WebOS components
colormake-0.9_1                Wrapper to color gmake output
dmake-4.12.20150309            Another hyper make utility
f1spirit-remake-1.0_13         Remake of classic F1 Spirit racing game
fmake-r250982                  Legacy FreeBSD pmake
gccmakedep-1.0.3               Create dependencies in makefiles using 'gcc -M'
gmake-4.1_2                    GNU version of 'make' utility
gmake-lite-4.1_1               Minimalist version of gnu make
gnustep-make-2.6.7_1           GNUstep makefile package
icmake-7.22.01                 Intelligent C-like Maker
imake-1.0.7,1                  Imake and other utilities from X.Org
libdungeonmaker-2.05_1         Program/library that "grows" dungeons for use in isometric games
libpagemaker-0.0.2             Library and tools for parsing Aldus/Adobe PageMaker documents
make++-2.0                     Drop-in replacement for GNU make
makedepend-1.0.5,1             Dependency generator for makefiles
makefaq-2.5                    Makefaq is a Python program that creates a (FAQ)
makehuman-0.9.1.r1.a_7         Application for parametrical modeling of 3D humanoid characters
makeindex-3.0.8_1              General purpose, formatter-independent index processor
makepasswd-1.10_6              Random password generator
makepatch-2.05_1               Perl scripts to assist in the generation and application of patches
makeself-2.2.0                 Neat script to make self-extracting archives
makeztxt-1.62                  Command line utility to create GutenPalm's zTXT format databases
menumaker-0.99.9               Menu generator for X Window Managers and desktop environments
mmake-2.3_1                    Create a Makefile for Your Java files, ready to compile
omake-0.9.8.6.0.r1_1           Flexible build system
p5-Class-MakeMethods-1.010_1   Generate common types of methods
p5-Class-MethodMaker-2.24      Perl module for creating generic methods
p5-DBICx-MapMaker-0.03_1       Perl 5 module to automatically create a DBIx::Class mapping table
p5-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10     Designed to write a Makefile for an extension module
p5-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-CPANfile-0.07 Cpanfile support for ExtUtils::MakeMaker
p5-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-Coverage-0.05_2 Add a Makefile target to determine test coverage using Devel::Cover
p5-Locale-Maketext-1.26        Framework for software localization and inheritance-based lexicons
p5-Locale-Maketext-Fuzzy-0.11_1 Maketext from already interpolated strings
p5-Locale-Maketext-Gettext-1.28_2 Joins gettext and Maketext frameworks
p5-Locale-Maketext-Lexicon-1.00 Use other catalog formats in Locale::Maketext
p5-Locale-Maketext-Simple-0.21_1 Simple interface to Locale::Maketext::Lexicon
p5-Make-1.00_1                 Perl module implementing 'make' and script
p5-Makefile-DOM-0.008_1        Simple DOM parser for Makefiles
p5-Makefile-Parser-0.216       Makefile::Parser - A Simple Parser for Makefiles
p5-Net-LDAP-Makepath-1.0.1_2   Provides a method for creating paths in LDAP simply
p5-SQL-Maker-1.21              Perl extension for yet another SQL builder
p5-Sort-Maker-0.06_1           Simple way to make efficient sort subs
pbimaker-1.3_1                 Program to convert ports into PBI modules
pilot_makedoc-0.7a_1           Converts text into the Doc format used by PalmPilots
premake-3.7_1                  Build script creation tool
premake4-4.4.b5                Build script creation tool
qmake-3.3.8_2                  The build utility of the Qt 3 project
qt4-makeqpf-4.8.7              Qt QPF2 font generator
qt4-qmake-4.8.7                Qt Makefile generator
qt5-qmake-5.4.1_4              Qt Makefile generator
remake-0.9                     Fork of gmake with debugger
smake-1.2.3                    Portable make program with automake features
texmaker-4.5,3                 LaTeX Development Environment
tmake-1.13                     Extremely portable perl-based make utility
unmakeself-1.1_1               Extract Makeself archives
windowmaker-0.95.7_1           GNUstep-compliant NeXTstep window manager clone
wmakerconf-2.12_11             Configuration tool for Window Maker
wsmake-0.7.901                 Software for production and maintenance of web sites
xmake-1.06_1                   Powerful make utility
xmakemol-5.16_5                Molecule Viewer Program Based on Motif Widget
xpi-passwordmaker-1.7.8        Manages all your online accounts using new or existing passwords
```

I have tested several packages from that list, but the `make` command does not appears on the system.

What is the **correct package** I must install?

Tested too the packages:

- gcc
- gmake
- make++

To let things clear: my problem is that I **don't have** any `make` tool installed on my bundled operating system:

```
[2.2.6-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.localdomain]/root: make
make: Command not found.
```

This is the **source code** (the drivers) that I need to compile:

```
$ ls -la
total 1088
d---rwx---+ 1 Luis None      0 ene  2 23:57 .
d---rwx---+ 1 Luis None      0 ene  2 23:57 ..
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   4600 sep  7  2008 bp_ioctl.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  42022 jun 12  2008 e1000_80003es2lan.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   4493 jun 12  2008 e1000_80003es2lan.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  22190 sep  4  2008 e1000_82540.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  39951 jun 12  2008 e1000_82541.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   4103 jun 12  2008 e1000_82541.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  16626 jun 12  2008 e1000_82542.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  48582 jun 12  2008 e1000_82543.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   2618 jun 12  2008 e1000_82543.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  48569 sep  4  2008 e1000_82571.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   2626 jun 12  2008 e1000_82571.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  35413 sep  4  2008 e1000_api.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   7596 jun 12  2008 e1000_api.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  74099 jun 12  2008 e1000_defines.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  24432 sep  4  2008 e1000_hw.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  79478 jun 12  2008 e1000_ich8lan.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   5647 jun 12  2008 e1000_ich8lan.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  63657 jun 12  2008 e1000_mac.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   5352 jun 12  2008 e1000_mac.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  11019 jun 12  2008 e1000_manage.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   3859 jun 12  2008 e1000_manage.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  23997 jun 12  2008 e1000_nvm.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   3374 jun 12  2008 e1000_nvm.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   3212 jun 12  2008 e1000_osdep.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   7457 jun 12  2008 e1000_osdep.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  79404 sep  2  2008 e1000_phy.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None   9327 jun 12  2008 e1000_phy.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  21371 jun 12  2008 e1000_regs.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  74859 sep  8  2008 em_bypass.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  12539 sep  8  2008 em_bypass.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  28352 sep  8  2008 em_sysctl.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None 185579 sep  7  2008 if_em.c
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  16571 sep  2  2008 if_em.h
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None    914 sep  2  2008 Makefile
----rwx---+ 1 Luis None  15264 sep  8  2008 silbpi.4
```

Comment: Without some hint of the problems found, no one (aside from someone with specific information about the package you are installing) will give good advice.  FreeBSD has a bundled *make* program (which was not mentioned).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I was thinking the problem was clear: there is no `make` tool on the system. I have edited original question to reflect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pfSense doesn't include `make` because [they don't think you should be compiling code on the firewall.](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Can_I_compile_software_on_pfSense)

> Q: Can I compile software on pfSense in the shell or console?
>  The
>   short answer: No
>   The long answer: No...

As they don't set it up as a build environment or test it, there will be more issues along the way. Best to heed their advice and do the compilation [on a matching FreeBSD release](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Versions_of_pfSense_and_FreeBSD). FreeBSD have [VM images to run](http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/VM-IMAGES/12.0-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/) for releases too. Then copy the compiled drivers across to pfSense.

Comment: I understand, Matt, but... compiling a driver is supposed (according to its doc) to generate multiple files on diferent paths, and/or modify some others. I don't know if that will be possible, but I will give it a try. Thanks you!

Comment: Run the `make` see what files are generated in the local directory. Then run the make install and see what it lists. If it's still not clear, the `Makefile` will include all the information and it should be fairly simple for a network driver